# Why don't the scuzzers pick up all the cargo containers in Startopia?

Tags: startopia

In Startopia I noticed that the scuzzers often won't pick up cargo that's been made by factories even when there are dozens of scuzzers on the engineering deck. It might be because I handled the cargo. Also, they leave some of the cargo to rot on the biodeck. Is there a way get them to pick up everything? Is there a way to know what isn't going to be picked up?

Answer (score 2):

Scuzzers prioritise construction and maintenance over hauling cargo to the cargo bay. If cargo is being left around, it's because your scuzzers are too busy with other tasks- buy or make more.

You can also help them by manually beaming cargo to the cargo bay.

Answer (score 2):

Scuzzers do four different actions:

1. Construction
2. Carrying cargo
3. Repairing
4. Cleaning

You can change the priority of these tasks by right-clicking individual scuzzers and changing the order of the four vertically-stacked icons in the middle of the panel. There's also a "Link" button, that looks like a chain, that orders your scuzzers to all follow that priority. (So if you want 50 scuzzers that prioritize cleaning, and just 5 that do construction, you'll set up the cleaning priority, click the Link button, and then find five individuals to make your construction workers by putting the construction icon on top.)

So if your scuzzers are leaving things around, re-prioritize a few to do cargo hauling first and everything else second. (If you're constantly constructing new buildings, then much of your scuzzer workforce is going to be running towards your ordered buildings rather than crates.)

Also, check if you have a bunch of unpowered scuzzers, and/or enough charging stations to keep your scuzzer fleet working. You'll get a notification every time a scuzzer runs out of power, but only *one* notification – so if you were distracted by something else when those notifications came in, and dismissed the lot, you won't be told again.